# Fail maven multi module test execution when surefire goes Out Of Memory

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

We use `maven-surefire` for executing tests in maven multi-module project. We use `<forkMode>once</forkMode>`. We also specify certain xmx value in surefire configuration like below

```
<argLine>-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError ${argLine}</argLine>
```

Now when certain module goes OOM during test execution, surefire execution of that JVM module terminates but build continue with the execution of tests in other modules.

Can someone let me know if it is possible to fail the maven top level build when surefire crashes due to OOM in any build?

The tests are executed in jenkins so `fail-on-end` is set to true i.e if there is any test assertion failure then I would like to continue with the execution of other tests like it is now, so that I get a complete report of all the test assertion failure in all modules.

- Surefire Version - 2.22.2
- Maven Version - 3.6.3

Comment: First question: Are those tests really unit tests? It looks strange having unit tests failing with OOM ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes it is unit test. I know it is a bit strange but that is how it is.

Comment: @khmarbaise - You can consider the more generic if for some reason surefire jvm crash for a module then I want to fail the top level maven test build to fail that is not the way it happens now with `fail-on-end`.

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade to 3.0.0-M4 of surefire plugin furthermore I have my doubts that your unit tests are unit tests...such amount of memory is usually an indicator for integration tests...